# Cannot Delete an AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I want to delete an AWS VPC which I don't know how it came into existence. When I try to delete it in AWS Console, it says:

[image]

> We could not delete the following VPC (vpc-0a72ac71) Network interface
>   'eni-ce2a0d10' is currently in use. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code:
>   400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID:
>   821d8a6d-3d9b-4c24-b372-314ea9b18b23)

As it mentions "AmazonEC2" in the error message, I suspected there might be some EC2 instances residing in this VPC. So I went into EC2 dashboard but found no EC2 exist there. However,  I found there are two security groups associated with this vpc. So I decided to delete them hoping that's the cause of the error. But when I tried to do so, I got this message:

[image]

As the message says, these security groups are associated with some network interfaces. Therefore, I decided to 'Detach' those but I got this error message:

[image]

> Error deleting network interfaces eni-ce2a0d10: You do not have
>   permission to access the specified resource. eni-0b7ff712: You do not
>   have permission to access the specified resource.

But I'm the root user so I assume I should be able to do whatever I want to do except if the resource is made by aws itself or another root account.

I know somewhere this network interface is being used but it will be very time-consuming to go through each aws service and check that.

I've already checked AWS RDS service and no instance or rds subnet is made. 
I've already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325336/i-cant-delete-my-vpc?rq=1)  and [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=591163) with no luck.

Comment: I recommend to move it to serverfault.

Comment: Did you perhaps do some testing with Workspaces or Workmail? *"...interface for directory..."* it says in your screenshot.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot sharp eyes you have! I noticed that too but as I could not answer my own question immediately, I had to wait two days to post it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot but how did you guess that directory should be related to a workspace or work email?

Comment: I assumed that if you had a directory service that you didn't remember starting, it must have been one you created during the quick-start process of one of those services -- it's easy to forget having done it. From the Workdocs Administrator Guide, [*"In the Set up a Directory page, choose Create Simple AD ... For VPC Details, you can either use an existing VPC, or have Amazon WorkDocs create and configure a VPC for you. To have Amazon WorkDocs create the VPC for you, select Set up a new VPC on my behalf.*"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workdocs/latest/adminguide/cloud_standard_setup.html)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That's exactly what I did! How does Amazon expect us to now this? I mean they could have put some comments in the related VPC saying how it came into existence.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the root cause of this issue.

**Short Answer**:

That VPC was created solely for the WorkDocs service instance. So AWS was preventing me to delete its VPC and any of its dependent services and pieces.

**How I figured it out:**

First, I noticed something interesting has been written in the 'Description' column of the 'undeletable' Network Interfaces (you can see them in the last OP's figure):

"AWS created network interface for **directory** d-90672d6b72."

From "directory", I suspected that this might have something do to with AWS Directory Service. So I went to this service and noticed there is a directory associated with the VPC:

[image]

So I tried to remove this directory but I got this error message:

> Error - Directory cannot be deleted This directory still has
>   authorized applications, and cannot be deleted.  To delete this
>   directory, complete all of the following steps:   • Delete the WorkDocs
>   site attached to this directory.

Therefore, I went to AWS WorkDocs Service and found it and deleted it:

[image: Deleting an AWS WorkDocs and its associated 'directory']

So now the directory is also deleted (circled in red), I went back to delete those network interfaces. However I realized that they are vanished! (I guess Amazon removed them on its own). I went to VPC service to see whether I'm now able to delete the VPC. Guess what? That VPC was vanished too!

**Now I understand what was happening. That VPC was created solely for the WorkDocs service instance. I wish Amazon was more transparent about it.**

Comment: As mentioned above, it is documented, but it goes by quickly when you run through the quick-start process. [The charges are waived](https://aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/other-directories-pricing/) for the Directory Service instances when you have Workspaces, Workdocs, or WorkMail attached to them.

Answer (score 2):

As a more generic answer to the "Error deleting network interface" issue, it happens when a network interface was created automatically for a higher-level AWS resource.

The **Generic solution** is to manage the network interface in the higher level resource directly such as WorkDocs or EFS.

In my case it happened when I wanted to delete a security group assigned to network interfaces created by an EFS volume.

So I went in the EFS console and removed the security group from the EFS.